# Not able to mount via HDFS NFS gateway

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

hadoop **version** : Hadoop 2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950

I want to setup a NFS Gateway for the Hadoop cluster we are having. I was following this nicely wrote guide [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.2.8/bk_hdfs_nfs_gateway/content/hdfs-nfs-gateway-user-guide.html).

### Config

I did all the mentioned steps above, added following configs as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292015/1610034):

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

### Setup Validation:

I have restarted data nodes after changing config. When I try from other machine, I get following responses:

```
saurabh@448140:~$ rpcinfo -p 10.33.37.220
   program vers proto   port
    100005    3   udp   4242  mountd
    100005    1   tcp   4242  mountd
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100005    3   tcp   4242  mountd
    100005    2   tcp   4242  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100005    2   udp   4242  mountd
    100005    1   udp   4242  mountd
saurabh@448140:~$ sudo showmount -e 10.33.37.220
Export list for 10.33.37.220:
/ *
```

### Error

But still I am getting following error, when trying to mount using this command: `sudo mount -v -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock NFSIP:/ /mountDir`:

```
18/04/04 19:32:48 WARN nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3: Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: root is not allowed to impersonate root
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getFileLinkInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileLinkInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:784)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getFileLinkInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileLinkInfo(DFSClient.java:2156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3Utils.getFileStatus(Nfs3Utils.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.Nfs3Utils.getFileAttr(Nfs3Utils.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3.fsinfo(RpcProgramNfs3.java:1969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3.fsinfo(RpcProgramNfs3.java:1925)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3.handleInternal(RpcProgramNfs3.java:2251)
        at org.apache.hadoop.oncrpc.RpcProgram.messageReceived(RpcProgram.java:167)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.oncrpc.RpcUtil$RpcMessageParserStage.messageReceived(RpcUtil.java:132)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is your container running as root user?

Comment: @user2249207 DataNode, RegionServer etc are being  run by user named `hdfs`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259911/hue-hive-user-root-is-not-allowed-to-impersonate-hue

Comment: @user2249207 I have added these configurations, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: You need to restart the namenode. That's where user permissions are verified

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, again restarting namenode fixed it, earlier I did, but seems that did not trigger or something. Thanks.